# tensorflow built from source using cuda or not?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built tensorflow with GPU support from source for python on macOS following the official instructions. When I import tensorflow though, I don't get the typical CUDA loading messages I do when I use the pip version (as below).

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
```

However, when I run my test program with my build, I do see that the GPU is being found and used (I think).

```
~/Drive/thesis/image_keras$ python3 demo.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 2125 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 832 images belonging to 2 classes.
demo.py:64: UserWarning: Update your `fit_generator` call to the Keras 2 API: `fit_generator(<keras.pre..., validation_data=<keras.pre..., steps_per_epoch=128, epochs=25, validation_steps=832)`
  nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
Epoch 1/25
2017-04-13 08:39:24.542434: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:865] OS X does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2017-04-13 08:39:24.542538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 750M
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.9255
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 2.00GiB
Free memory: 1.77GiB
2017-04-13 08:39:24.542551: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-04-13 08:39:24.542557: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-04-13 08:39:24.542566: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 750M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
 49/128 [==========>...................] - ETA: 18s - loss: 0.7352 - acc: 0.5166
```

It looks like its using GPU, but without the CUDA loading I'm not sure. If it makes a difference I am running `CUDA-8.0` with `cuDNN-8.0-v5.1`

Answer (score 0):

```
tensorflow.test.is_gpu_available()
tensorflow.test.is_built_with_cuda()
```

If you run these codes, and Tensorflow is built with CUDA, then both functions should return **True**.

I have to use this, because as given in the previous answer, I don't get a output with "successfully opened CUDA library" lines printed as shown, even though I'm using the pip version. 
I use Tensorflow 1.4.0.